# TypeScript "Could not find a declaration file" error on some Node.js versions

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm trying to set the `"noImplicitAny": true` option for an existing TypeScript project. After making all the necessary code changes I'm getting the following error for one of our dependencies on Node 6 and 7:

`Could not find a declaration file for module '@firebase/database'. '/home/travis/build/firebase/firebase-admin-node/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

This works fine on Node 8 (both locally and on Travis CI).

Does anybody know why this is? I can kind of understand the error, but no clue why it happens only on certain versions of Node.

**Edit**

Added the `traceResolution` option, and I do see a difference in how the dependency gets resolved between Node 7 and 8.

On Node 8:

```
'package.json' has 'typings' field 'dist/index.d.ts' that references '/home/travis/build/firebase/firebase-admin-node/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.d.ts'.
File '/home/travis/build/firebase/firebase-admin-node/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.d.ts' exist - use it as a name resolution result.
Resolving real path for '/home/travis/build/firebase/firebase-admin-node/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.d.ts', result '/home/travis/build/firebase/firebase-admin-node/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.d.ts'.
======== Module name '@firebase/database' was successfully resolved to '/home/travis/build/firebase/firebase-admin-node/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.d.ts'. ========
```

On Node 7:

```
'package.json' has 'typings' field 'dist/index.d.ts' that references '/home/travis/build/firebase/firebase-admin-node/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.d.ts'.
File '/home/travis/build/firebase/firebase-admin-node/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.d.ts' does not exist.
Loading module as file / folder, candidate module location '/home/travis/build/firebase/firebase-admin-node/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.d.ts', target file type 'TypeScript'.
File '/home/travis/build/firebase/firebase-admin-node/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.d.ts.ts' does not exist.
...
File '/home/travis/build/firebase/firebase-admin-node/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js' exist - use it as a name resolution result.
Resolving real path for '/home/travis/build/firebase/firebase-admin-node/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js', result '/home/travis/build/firebase/firebase-admin-node/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js'.
======== Module name '@firebase/database' was successfully resolved to '/home/travis/build/firebase/firebase-admin-node/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js'. ========
```

Comment: is the package.json the same for both?

Comment: Yes. We have a Travis CI job that checks out the project from GitHub and builds it on Node 6, 7 and 8. Only the last one passes.

Comment: Try setting `"traceResolution": true` in the compiler options in your tsconfig.json to get more information about where TypeScript is looking for the declaration file.

Comment: That was useful. I do see a difference in how the module is resolved (I've added the output to the question as an edit). No idea what's causing the difference though.

Comment: It says on npm not to use this package directly. Is this a sub-dependency or a direct dependency of your module?

Comment: It is a direct dependency. Ours is also a Firebase library in the same ecosystem. It seems the `index.d.ts` file got dropped from the 0.3.2 release of the `@firebase/database` package, and on Node 8 NPM installed 0.3.1 (this version is specified in our package-lock file). Older versions of Node/NPM are ignoring the package-lock file and installing the latest version of the dependency, which has this problem. We'll work with the authors of @firebase/database to get this sorted out. Thanks all for the help.

Comment: You should specify the exact version on your `package.json`. The `package-lock.json` is not where you specify version requirements, and in majority of cases you should not be modifying that file.

Comment: Version is set in package.json but as "^0.3.1". The package-lock file is essentially anchoring the dependency version to 0.3.1 on CI.